# is it possible to create a delay between each page build? (Next.js ISR)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

I am working on some project that I need to use ISR on, the pages critical info come from a third-party API, the problem is that this API allows only a maximum of 15 requests per second while the pages I need to be generated are hundreds and it needs hundreds of requests at build time, (by the fetching code ran inside getStaticProps()), so this obviously exceeds the limit of the APIs allowed requests per second,

How can I possibly solve that??
Is there any configuration for this matter that I don't know of or something to create a time gap between each page build?

Btw, I already tried making a delay before an API request happens using promises and timeout but that just doesn't work for some reason, would be glad if someone explained...